# How to set dll search path of MSTest used with opencover?

Tags: mstest, opencover

My unit tests have dependencies which are from a pool of dlls in a directory outside of the project. We have the policy to generally place links to these dlls (from the pool) in a directory called "System" inside the project directory and set their `CopyToOutputDirectory` to `PreserveNewest`. Afterwards, in the project we add a reference to the dll in the pool but set it to be *not* a private copy which means it will not be output to the build dir. In the `InitAssembly()` method we have setup that the runtime searches also in the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "System")` by the means of `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve`.

```
[TestClass]
public class SomeUnitTest : OurUnitTestBase
{
  [AssemblyInitialize]
  public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine("in AssemblyInit");
    base.InitAssembly();
  }
}
```

This works nice when running our code from inside VisualStudio and also when running the unit tests from inside VisualStudio's Test-Explorer (vstest.executionengine.x86.exe). However MSTest fails to find the dlls in the System subdirectory when run from the following batch script which executes a coverage analysis with opencover:

```
REM Bring dev tools into the PATH.
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat"

mkdir .\CoverageAnalysisReport

REM Run unit tests through OpenCover
REM This allows OpenCover to gather code coverage results
.\..\..\Tools\CoverageAnalysis\opencover\OpenCover.Console.exe^
  -register:user^
  -target:MSTest.exe^  
  -targetargs:"/noresults /noisolation /testcontainer:..\bin\Debug\OurUnitTests.dll"^
  -filter:+[*]*^
  -output:.\CoverageAnalysisReport\output.xml

REM Generate the report
.\..\..\Tools\CoverageAnalysis\ReportGenerator\bin\ReportGenerator.exe^
  -reports:.\CoverageAnalysisReport\output.xml^
  -targetdir:.\CoverageAnalysisReport^
  -reporttypes:HTML^
  -filters:-OurUnitTests*

REM Open the report
start .\CoverageAnalysisReport\index.htm
```

The resulting log file says, that none of the unit tests could be run and failed therefore. Furthermore it states

```
Warning: The assembly "BaseLib" as a direct or indirect dependency of the test container "C:\MyProject\bin\debug\ourunittests.dll" was not found.
```

Yet I know [AssemblyInitialize] was called because a `System.Windows.Form.MessageBox.Show(..)` I placed there temporarily actually got displayed during the execution of the bat-file.

Is there a way to tell MSTest to search also for dlls in the System subdirectory also?

Comment: Can you run mstest on the command line, or vstest.console.exe, without OpenCover? OpenCover shouldn't interfere with how the program runs if it is then raise an issue on github with a sample that fails when running under OpenCover.

Comment: I have to admit, that the issue has nothing to do with OpenCover. I have to look into how I can get mstest to run successfully on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by placing the following as the content of a file named `Local.testsettings` in the same directory like the batch file (in which I modified the line `-targetargs:"/testcontainer:\"..\bin\x86\Debug\OurUnitTests.dll\" /testSettings:\".\Local.testsettings\"`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestSettings name="Lokal" id="2fa4344c-1f2f-4a04-86f3-41d223b10333" xmlns="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010">
  <Description>Dies sind die standardmäßigen Testeinstellungen für einen lokalen Testlauf.</Description>
  <Deployment>
    <DeploymentItem filename="..\bin\Debug\System\" />
  </Deployment>
  <Execution>
    <TestTypeSpecific>
      <UnitTestRunConfig testTypeId="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b">
        <AssemblyResolution>
          <TestDirectory useLoadContext="true" />
        </AssemblyResolution>
      </UnitTestRunConfig>
    </TestTypeSpecific>
    <AgentRule name="Execution Agents">
    </AgentRule>
  </Execution>
</TestSettings>
```